# Jquery : Play video in bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i want to play video when item gets active class in bootstrap slider below is my code

```
<div class="item" id='mobileapp'>
  <video loop controls width="100%" id='video'>
    <source src="../../vid.mp4" width="100%" height="100%" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>    
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h1 class="super-heading text-white">Heading</h1>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1'>
        <img src='../img/googleplay.png' class='img-responsive hidden-xs' />
      </div>   
      <div class='col-sm-2'>
        <img src='../img/applestore.png' class='img-responsive hidden-xs' />
      </div>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#mobileapp').hasClass('active')) {
      $('#video')[0].play();
    }
    else {
      $('#video')[0].pause();
    }

  })
</script>
```

active class gets added but it does not pay video

Answer (score 0):

the functions 'play' and 'pause' are not jquery functions, they belong to the DOM element. Now to make it work try to execute your code every 10 miliseconds or something like that.
Try:

```js
var videoElt = document.getElementById('video');

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
      if ($('#mobileapp').hasClass('active')) {
        videoElt.play(); // to play the video
      }
      else {
        videoElt.pause(); // to pause the video
      }
    }, 10);

});
```

Comment: stil not playing

Comment: actually if statement is not executing , if class gets added should this if run?

Comment: try a `console.log($('#mobileapp').hasClass('active'))` in the console and see the output

Comment: always false even if it has active class

Comment: You'll have to use vanilla javascript then. test with `console.log(document.getElementById('mobileapp').classList.contains('active'))`

Comment: still false always